# Black Border in External Monitor OSX El Capitan 1920 x 1080

Tags: display, macos

I've got this issue with OSX El Capitan. My existing monitor show black border in resolution 1920 x 1080. The black border is shown only on left side of monitor. This never happen previously in Yosemite.

What I've tried but didn't work:

- set resolution in safe mode
- unplug and plug again my mini to VGA cable
- Restart
- play with my monitor setting (reset setting)

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with my Acer monitor. I've researched a lot online. Next few days my ordered VGA-DVId will test my last resort. So I suggest you might change your monitor's input to DVI. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using El Capitan on a 15" MacBook Pro, with an external monitor plugged in hdmi (using mini-display to hdmi adapter).
This morning, I have plugged the monitor to my laptop, and then hit power-on.

On starting, a large black border appeared at the top + bottom of my macbook pro screen (not the external).
After many unsuccessful reboot, I have tried to stop all applications started on my previous session, and reboot.
This has solved my problem, now I have the real full-screen.